# displaying 2 tables in one listview on VB6.0

Tags: listview, vb6

i am currently developing my vb6 program but having a problem in displaying one listview from two tables .. on first try it runs correctly, it stores my info like name, address, age etc. on their assigned columns but on the second run. the infos multiplies and just placed on the 1st column of the list view :( 
here is my code on the listview form:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
.open "Select * from tblapps , tblappsinfo", cn, 3, 3
ListView1.ListItems.Clear
Do Until rs.EOF
    ListView1.ListItems.Add = !Name
    ListView1.ListItems.Item(1).ListSubItems.Add = !address
    ListView1.ListItems.Item(1).ListSubItems.Add = !tin
    ListView1.ListItems.Item(1).ListSubItems.Add = !cel
    ListView1.ListItems.Item(1).ListSubItems.Add = !College
    ListView1.ListItems.Item(1).ListSubItems.Add = !age
    ListView1.ListItems.Item(1).ListSubItems.Add = !Status
    ListView1.ListItems.Item(1).ListSubItems.Add = !Salary_Desired
    ListView1.ListItems.Item(1).ListSubItems.Add = !Hours_can_work
    ListView1.ListItems.Item(1).ListSubItems.Add = !Available_for_work



  .MoveNext
  Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not updating the index for the item when you're adding sub-items for subsequent records, it's always adding it to `Item(1)`.

What you want instead in your example is

```
ListView1.ListItems.Item(ListView1.ListItems.Count)
```

that way the sub-items are always being added to the newest item.

But be careful!  If the Sorted property is true while adding, the most recent may not be the last one. In that case, you could add each item with the name as its own key:

```
ListView1.ListItems.Add , !Name, !Name
```

then reference by the key instead of the index

```
ListView1.ListItems.Item(!Name)
```

However, it's probably better and easier (avoiding key collision issues) to just turn off sorting before the loop with `ListView1.Sorted = False` and turn it back on after the loop with `ListView1.Sorted = True`.